# Training with Custom Container doesn't finish after main script is done

Tags: python, docker, tensorflow, google-cloud-ml, gcp-ai-platform-training

I am training an object detection model with tensorflow and the object detection api using a Docker container on Google Cloud AI Platform. After the training finishes, a tflite graph is successfully exported but the problem is that the job doesn't finish after `main.py` finishes.

To train the model and exporting I use a `main.py` script as entrypoint:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["python", "-u", "main.py"]
```

and the script takes some arguments which I pass to it using the `CMD` keyword inside the Dockerfile (although they can get overwritten using the `gcloud ai-platform jobs submit training` command):

```
CMD ["--network_type", "mobilenet_v2_ssd", \
     "--train_whole_model", "True", \
     "--job-dir", "gs://job-dir", \
     "--dataset-dir", "gs://dataset"]
```

The content of `main.py` basically looks like this:

```
# import stuff

# define argparse stuff

def main(args):
    # Train Model
    # Export Graph
    print("Training finished")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # get args
    main(args)
```

To start the job I execute the following:

```
gcloud ai-platform jobs submit training $JOB_NAME \
    --region $REGION \
    --config config.yaml \
    --job-dir "gs://job-dir" \
    --master-image-uri $IMAGE_URI \
    -- \
    --network_type "mobilenet_v2_ssd" \
    --train_whole_model "True" \
    --dataset-dir "gs://dataset" \
```

When I see the `Training finished` in the Google Cloud Log Viewer the container runs at least five minutes without finishing and I don't know if it would stop if I don't cancel the job manually.

Do I have to instruct AI Platform to finish the job at the end of `main.py`? Maybe returning a status code (e.g. `return 0`)? Or should I just wait more than five minutes for the job to finish by itself?

Comment: Can you try to run your container locally to see if it exits by itself? It might be the case that your container was still running somehow. If you issue a cancel request, the service will kill your container regardless.

Comment: @GuoqingXu thanks for your help. Unfortunately the task is quite long running so I didn't test locally yet. However, I added `return 0` to the python code and ran the container again to see if it exits after giving it some more time. This time it exited immediately after the `main.py` finished with its final logging message. As you mention the container maybe got in some unfinished state without the `return 0` but I guess this needs some more testing.